# Excel get last data in column and return value from different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that I've created in excel that dynamically inputs data from a stock so my column A is growing every day.

I'm looking for a formula that will search column A for the last data available then return back that row's column H. So based on the photo, it would return the value `-0.14`.

I've figured out how to get to the last cell with data in column A but can't figure out how to pull information from that row's column H (I can't apply that same method to column H because that column has `0s` throughout)

```
= INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok this would seem to be straightforward to me if you Vlookup from that last found cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with your formula. Just replace column `A:A` with `H:H`. The final formula will be:

```
=INDEX(H:H,COUNT(A:A))
```

Be aware that this formula **won't work if you have blanks** in your data (since it won't count them). In this case you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(H:H,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
```

The term `MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))` will find the highest row number that is not a blank and return it to the `INDEX` function, which picks the corresponding value from column `H`